# Multiple parameters in @Url.Action in MVC 4 .NET Razor

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created this  link on my cshtml page:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Contacts", new { pagenumber = ViewData["contact_scroll"].ToString(), clickContact = "1", contact_id = contact.id })">
```

Although all three keys are not null and the url showed when I put the mouse over the link is correct:

```
Edit?pagenumber=0&clickContact=1&contact_id=307
```

if I put a breakpoint at the begin of the ActionResult Edit, in the Request.QueryString keys, there is only the contact_id value. The RawUrl of the Request object contains only:

```
/Contacts/Edit?contact_id=299
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If you view the HTTP request using something like chrome developer tools or fiddler does it include any of the other fields when sent? Also, what does your controller edit action look like?

Comment: you have to Map route values in `Global.ascx.cs` with `routes.MapRoute()` if you are in controller `ActionResult`

Comment: If I copy the HTML from the link in the Chrome developer tools, I obtain this: <a href="/Contacts/Edit?pagenumber=0&amp;clickContact=1&amp;contact_id=307">John unset</a>

Comment: What is the correct way to add the route with three parameters in the Global.ascx.cs?